# Increment value from 1 to onward based on other field in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

| id | result |
| --- | --- |
| KLLR | 1 |
| KLLR | 2 |
| KLLR | 3 |
| KLLR | 4 |
| OLRQ | 1 |
| OLRQ | 2 |
| PKRD | 1 |
| PKRD | 2 |
| PKRD | 3 |

SQL increment value from 1 to onward based on other fields and the output calculated field is the result. Please view the image for more clarity. And below is my SQL which I tried. I want the result in another calculated field as you can see in the image.

```
SELECT id, SUM(COUNT(id)) AS result
FROM t1 
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Please tag appropriately.  MySQL and SQL Server are completely different products with different dialects of SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple row number should work for you here:

```
SELECT id,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS Result
FROM t1;
```

You tagged both MySQL and SQL Server.  Do note that they are completely different products but the same should work in both.  MySQL introduced `ROW_NUMBER()` in 8.0.

Toward HansG's comment,

```
SELECT id,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Result
FROM t1;
```

will give you the random ordering mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for answering. However I got the this error after writing above query "Msg 4112, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
The function 'ROW_NUMBER' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY."

Comment: Need to know the version & actual RDBMS then

Comment: You could add order by (SELECT NULL)  for random ordering or use any column you'd like to order on by specifying the name

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: @SalmanSabir I fixed your tags.  I also fixed my post, see the update.  Sorry, I initially ommitted the ORDER BY....

Comment: @squillman Thank you so much. And now I got what I wanted and the query is working really fine. HansG and xQbert thank you too. Thank you for all of your support.

Comment: @squillman I am using OpenQuery and my data source is from MySQL that is why I give the tag to MySQL as well.

Comment: Ok, then it'd be better to be clear about that in the question.  You really only need to tag the database platform where the query is actually going to be run, which in the case of OpenQuery would be MySQL.  The SQL Server part is just a wrapper.

Comment: Wouldn't order by null put gaps such that PKDR could get #1 result assigned multiple times for the same PKDR ID?  I think order by ID makes sense in this case; but the point is valid.

Comment: @xQbert No it would not. And `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` makes the meaning clear: the order is random within each partition

Comment: select * from OpenQuery ([CALL],' SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS Result
FROM (select uniqueId from t1 where id in (select distinct id from t1 where j_id="52554");')

Comment: Above is my query. How to achieve this when you have where clause and some other field with condition as above.

Comment: @Charlieface  wow brain fart. I agree.  Not sure why I lost sight of the partition as being the key of the number sequence.